# Use different shader programs in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I have to use two different shader programs in OpenGL for different objects.

I found that I have to use `glUseProgram()` to switch between different shader programs, but not much information on that.

How does generating and binding VAOs and VBOs work for each shader program (how & when) given that I have two different shader programs I use for different objects?

Comment: I'll try to put this delicately... you said "I am pretty familiar with OpenGL overall by now," but it might help to approach the subject with more humility.  Modern OpenGL builds on a foundation of running shader programs, and most techniques are built on top of that foundation.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Well with pretty familiar I meant I did several Projects in University, of which some were pretty complex. But the thing is we always had to code base or it was not modern openGL. So I am facing this specific part the first time, and this is how I asked this question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you render objects in OpenGL, your code will look like this:

- Bind program with `glUseProgram`, set uniforms with `glUniform4fv`, `glUniformMatrix4fv`, etc.
- Bind the vertex array with `glBindVertexArray`.
- Bind any textures you need with `glActiveTexture` and `glBindTexture`.
- Change any other state, e.g., `glEnable`, `glDisable`, `glBlendFunc`.
- Draw with `glDrawArrays` or `glDrawElements`.
- If you want, reset state back to defaults.

These are all the things that you tend to do in vanilla OpenGL 3 code.  You should already have this part working.

If you need to write multiple objects with different shader programs, you just do the above steps multiple times.  State changes can be omitted if you are going to use the same state for multiple programs (except uniforms, which are saved separately for each program).  For example, you might use the same VAO, the same textures, the same blending function, et cetera.

There are many tutorials on how OpenGL 3 drawing commands work, if you are looking for more detailed examples.

Comment: In addition: If you want to use the same VAO with different shaders, you have to make sure that the input variables have the same location in both shaders

Comment: @DietrichEpp So if I render different objects in two different VAOs, I just bind the program and bind the VAO for the one objects and shaders, and then do the same for the other objects and shaders? Just for clearification. If so it is very straight forward and I don't know what confused me that much, since I actually have the part working you mentioned I should have...

Comment: You're asking if you have two VAOs and two programs?  Yes, you would bind one program + VAO, draw, then bind the other program + VAO, then draw.  It is of course also possible to have one VAO and two programs, or two VAOs and one program.

Comment: Program objects retain their arguments from last time they were set. See my answer.

Comment: @enigmaticPhysicist: When you say "arguments" my guess is that you are talking about uniforms? Good catch, I've clarified that the uniforms are per-program.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: uniforms and attributes are remembered. It is only attribute indices, though, that need to be unique among programs in order to be able to switch without respecifying arguments.

Comment: @enigmaticPhysicist: I'm not sure what you mean when you say that attributes are remembered. The attribute bindings are in the VAO, they are explicitly not part of the program state.

Comment: Right, I see what you mean, @DietrichEpp. The programs don't in fact remember anything about the attribute arrays. They refer to arrays through an index, though, and as long as those indices are unique among all programs you are switching between, you do not need to have separate VAOs for each program. All attribute arrays may be contained within a single VAO. See my answer.

Comment: @enigmaticPhysicist: That won’t work because it’s often not practical to make the indexes different across all of your programs. Indexes must be in the range from 0 to GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS-1, and a common value for GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS is only 16! There simply aren’t enough unique indexes to go around.

Comment: You don't need enough for all your programs. Just the ones you want to switch rapidly in between.

Comment: I can already switch rapidly between different programs by using VAOs, which are mandatory in modern OpenGL anyway. Maybe you are writing different kind of programs, but I don't think it's that uncommon to have a shader program that uses more than 8 attribute indexes. Remember that a single matrix attribute will use up multiple indexes, so if you have tangent-space normal maps you are probably going to use 3 indexes just for those.

Comment: @enigmaticPhysicist: I'm also not sure how this trick makes anything more rapid. With VAOs, it's already very rapid to switch between different VBOs.

Comment: It's not for switching rapidly between VBOs. It's for switching rapidly between programs. Look, I'm not going to sit here and try to compensate for your lack of creativity. Figure it out. I'm done here.

Comment: How fast is the switch between GL programs described in the answer?  Is it rapid enough to permit this switch to happen (potentially multiple times) per rendered frame in a, say, 60Hz framerate? (Yes, I'm new to OpenGL)

Comment: @IllvilJa: You can also try this out yourself. But, yes. You can switch shaders many times per frame. If you couldn’t, it would be impossible to use multiple shaders in real-time!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to switch program objects without having to specify their arguments all over again. In order for it to work, though, you must pre-assign the values of your vertex attribute array indices before compiling and linking, using `glBindAttribLocation`, making sure each of your programs uses separate indices. If you don't, then the same VBO may go to both programs. The VBOs being used by both programs must all be in the same VAO, which must be bound while the programs are active and the Draw commands are executed.

Here's an example:

```
// HELPER FUNCTIONS
// ================
// Read a file to a string.
char *load(const char *fn)
{
    int fd = open(fn, O_RDONLY);
    assert(fd != -1);

    off_t size = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
    assert(size != -1);
    off_t res = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
    assert(res != -1);

    size++;  // null terminator
    char *buf = (char *)malloc(size);

    char *p = buf;
    for (;;) {
        // File has gotten bigger since we started? Fuck that.
        assert(p - buf < size);
        ssize_t nread = read(fd, (char *)p, 0x10000);
        assert(nread != -1);
        if (nread == 0) {
            *p = '\0';
            break;
        }

#ifndef NDEBUG
        // Null character? Fuck that shit.
        void *nullbyte = memchr((char *)p, '\0', nread);
        assert(nullbyte == NULL);
#endif

        p += nread;
    }
    int cres = close(fd);
    assert(cres == 0);

    return buf;
}

// Compile the "type" shader named "filename" and attach it to
// "shader_program".
static void compile_shader(GLenum type, const char *filename,
        GLuint shader_program)
{
    GLuint shader = glCreateShader(type);
    char *source = load(filename);
    glShaderSource(shader, 1, &source, 0);
    glCompileShader(shader);
#ifndef NDEBUG
    GLint success;
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        GLint log_length;
        glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &log_length);
        char *log = (char *)malloc(log_length);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, log_length, NULL, log);
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to compile %s:\n%s", filename, log);
        abort();
    }
#endif
    glAttachShader(shader_program, shader);
}
// Return a shader program with vertex shader "vertfile" and the fragment
// shader "fragfile". The program is not linked, in case stuff still needs to
// be added.
GLuint compile_shader_program(const char *vertfile, const char *fragfile)
{
    GLuint p = glCreateProgram();
    compile_shader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertfile, p);
    compile_shader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragfile, p);
    return p;
}


// . . . 


// INIT
// ====

// Make and bind the VAO, shared between both programs.
GLuint vao;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);

// Init one_program.
float square[] = {0.f, 0.f,  1.f, 0.f,  0.f, 1.f,  1.f, 1.f};
GLuint vbo;
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(square), square, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
// Make sure these indices are unique among all VBOs you are using to render.
GLuint attr = 0;
glEnableVertexAttribArray(attr);
glVertexAttribPointer(attr, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

GLuint one_program = compile_shader_program("glsl/2d.vert", "glsl/white.frag");
glBindAttribLocation(one_program, attr, "vertex_pos");
glLinkProgram(one_program);

// Set uniforms.
// . . .

// Do the same thing for the_other_program.
float triangle[] = {0.f, 0.f,  1.f, 0.f,  0.f, 1.f};
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(square), square, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
attr++;
glEnableVertexAttribArray(attr);
glVertexAttribPointer(attr, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

GLuint the_other_program =
    compile_shader_program("glsl/2d.vert", "glsl/chrome.frag");
glBindAttribLocation(the_other_program, attr, "vertex_pos");
glLinkProgram(the_other_program);

// Set uniforms.
// . . .



// RENDER ONE FRAME
// ================
glUseProgram(one_program);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

glUseProgram(the_other_program);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 3);
```

Comment: This code looks like it’s from an older version of OpenGL than the question is asking about. The question mentions VAOs, which are mandatory in core profiles since version 3.2, but it appears that the code in this answer does not use VAOs at all and might be from an older version of OpenGL (2.1).

Comment: Oh. I didn't know VAOs were manditory since 3.2. But there's a good chance this will still work. I can't test this because I don't have a computer that supports opengl 3.2, if you can believe that. I bet you could get it working, though.

Comment: I just found out my computer actually does support VAOs even though it's only opengl2.1 (through the extension GL_ARB_vertex_array_object), so I was able to test these ideas on VAOs. It still works. I'm updating my answer now.

Comment: How old is your computer? OpenGL 3.2 is actually very old now, and if your computer has a discrete graphics card manufactured after 2007, or a CPU manufactured after 2010, then it probably supports OpenGL 3.3 or newer. However, you might need to request a “core context” during context creation to get something newer than OpenGL 2.1. This is true for both macOS and true for any Linux system which uses Mesa (which is true if you haven’t installed closed-source drivers).

Comment: Note that there is at least one major problem with this answer—there is a maximum value for attribute array indexes, and it can be quite small! The most common value for GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS is 16, so you might only get 16 different unique indexes.

Comment: Another potential problem is that this might potentially access vertex arrays out of range. For example, if you have one object with 20 vertices, and one object with 2000 vertices, what happens when both buffers are bound and active when you render the 2000 vertex object? Does this cause out of bounds access?

Comment: I’m also not sure how this would work with instanced rendering. I would say that reusing a single VAO this way is really misuse of VAOs entirely, and is likely only to create problems. I’m not sure what kind of performance problems this might or might not create, but I believe VAOs are used to cache certain server-side information about how to unpack vertex data. It would be interesting to run this code with KHR_debug enabled under different drivers to see if they gave any warnings about performance problems.

Comment: 16 is enough vertex attribs. You don't need to switch between all of your programs at once. Only the ones you need to switch rapidly between. I've read the opengl 3.2 standard pretty thoroughly, and I haven't done anything to violate it. 16 corresponds to the number of arguments of all programs you are using simultaneously. It does not correspond to the total number of VAOs you are using, which can be much higher.

Comment: Basically, you could treat two programs a single program, and always run them together. As long as the vertex attribute indices don't overlap between the two programs, you don't need to use separate VBOs for both programs.

Comment: This is from my graphics card's glxinfo:
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) G45/G43 
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 18.2.5
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20

Comment: Unfortunately, that hardware does not support OpenGL 3.x.

Comment: There are just so many problems with this answer. The major problem is that I don't see what this answer is trying to achieve. We already have VAOs, so it is very easy to switch between different VBOs. This answer appears to present a complicated and possibly error-prone method of sharing VAOs between programs, and it introduces extra constraints and limitations beyond what you would get with ordinary usage of VAOs. And I still don't see what possible benefit this trick would get you. Why would you *want* to use the same VAO for multiple programs?