# Using the same vertex array object for different shader programs

Tags: c++, glsl

my goal is to pack all mesh data into a C++ class, with the possibility of using an object of such a class with more than one GLSL shader program.

I've stuck with this problem: if I understand it well the way of how in GLSL vertex data are passed from CPU to GPU is based on using Vertex Array Objects which:

- are made of Vertex Buffer Objects which store raw vertex data, and
- Vertex Attribute Pointers which tells what shader variable location to assign and the format of the data passed to VBO above
- additionally one can make an Element Buffer Object to store indices
- another extra elements necessary to draw an object are textures which are made separately

I's able to make all that data and store only a VAO in my mesh class and only pass the VAO handler to my shader program to draw it. It works, but, for my goal of using multiple shader programs, the VAP stands in my way. It is the only element in my class that rely on a specific shader program's property (namely the location of input variables).

I wonder if I'm forced to remake all VAOs every time I'm using my shaders when I want to draw something. I'm afraid that the efficiency of my drawing code will suffer drastically.

So, I'm asking if I should forget of making my *universal* mesh class and instead make a separate objects for each shader program I'm using in my application. I would rather not, as I want to avoid unnecessary copying of my mesh data. On the other hand if this means my drawing routine will slow down because of all that remaking VAOs every milisecond during drawing then I have to rethink the design of my code :(

**EDIT**: OK I've misunderstood that VAOs store bindings to other objects, not the data itself. But there is one thing still left: to make an VAP I have to provide information about the location of an input variable *from a shader* and also the layout of data in VBO *from a mesh*.

What I'm trying to avoid is to make an separate object that stores that VAP which relies both on a mesh object and a shader object. I *might* solve my problem if all shader programs use the same location for the same thing, but at this moment I'm not sure if this is the case.

Comment: Just create one VAO per shader up front and bind the appropriate VAO when you want to draw using that shader? Note that switching VAOs has a non-zero cost, but still a lot better than recreating it every time.

Comment: @Botje Well, that's what I want to avoid as it means to copy again data for VBO's, EBO's and forces me to maintain a separate mapping object for every mesh+shader combo.

Comment: What do you mean by "copy again data"? Several VAOs can reference the same VBO.

Comment: The VAOs are just *bindings*, they do not hold any data but instead register "links".

Comment: @limserhane so how to rebind them? Probably an easy thing, but I wish to see some example code

Comment: If all your shaders have the same layout (for example they all use : attribute 0 = position, attribute 1 = normal, attribute 2 = uvs, ...), you do not need to rebind anything and it will work properly. If however this is not the case, then you will need more work. For example, you can initialize vaoDiffuse with some layout, and vaoWater with another layout, and then bind the right vao for the shader you are using.

Comment: Anyway, you can post parts of your code (like shader layouts and the vao initialization) so that we can give you better understanding.

Comment: Note that you do not bind a vertex attribute to a shader attribute, you bind it to a location (0, 1, 2, ... whatever you want). And then your shader declares the locations it needs, thats why one vao "works" with multiple shader if they have the same layout.

Comment: See [the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39923583/use-different-shader-programs-in-opengl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> additionally one can make an Element Buffer Object to store indices
>
> another extra elements necessary to draw an object are textures which are made separately

Just to be clear, that's you being lazy and/or uninformed. OpenGL strongly encourages you to use a single buffer for both vertex and index data. Vulkan goes a step further by limiting the number of object names (vao, vbo, textures, shaders, everything) you can create and actively punishes you for not doing that.

As to the problem you're facing.. It would help if you used correct nomenclature, or at least full names. "VAP" is yet another sign of laziness that hides what your actual issue is.

I will mention that VAOs are separate from VBOs, and you can have multiple VAOs linked to the same VBO (VBOs are just buffers of raw data -- again, Vulkan goes a step further here and its buffers store literally everything from vertex data, element indices, textures, shader constants etc).

You can also have multiple programs use the same VAOs, you just bind whatever VAO you want active (`glBindVertexArray`) once, then use your programs and call your render functions as needed. Here's an example from one of my projects that uses the same terrain data to render both the shaded terrain and a grid on top of them:

```
        chunk.VertexIndexBuffer.Bind();

        // pass 1, render the terrain 
        terrainShader.ProgramUniform("selectedPrimitiveID", selectedPrimitiveId);
        terrainShader.Use();
        roadsTexture.Bind();
        GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Triangles, 0, chunk.VertexIndexBuffer.VertexCount);

        // pass 2, render the grid
        gridShader.Use();
        GL.DrawElements(BeginMode.Lines, chunk.VertexIndexBuffer.IndexCount, DrawElementsType.UnsignedShort, 0);
```

Comment: "*Vulkan goes a step further by limiting the number of object names (vao, vbo, textures, shaders, everything) you can create and actively punishes you for not doing that.*" That's completely untrue. I know of only two limits to the number of objects Vulkan lets you create. You can only allocate X blocks of memory (where X is determined by the implementation). And there is a limit on the number of sampler objects you can create, also implementation-dependent. I know of no other per-object limits.

Comment: To that "lazy" + "uninformed" combo I would add a plain stupidity. I've never thought about looking at my problem upside-down and instead of trying to match meshes to shaders I should try to do the reverse. I'll try to redesign my application. Thanks!

Comment: @NicolBolas, that's right, you're limited in the number of objects you can create because of it. Which is perfectly fine, you can reuse the same buffers for multiple kinds of data.

Comment: @Blindy: "*that's right, you're limited in the number of objects you can create because of it*" You are in fact *not* limited in the number of objects you can create by the limitation on memory allocation blocks. Buffers and textures can overlap storage with each other (though with limitations). Also, the limitation on block allocations is merely exposing a platform-specific limitation to the user. My point is that you're suggesting that this limit exists to encourage user behavior instead of the actual purpose: a limitation of the OS/hardware.

Comment: And just so we're clear, texture object limits are also system-dependent, and as low as 300ish on some devices. Descriptor objects are also limited, up to 4K base (though I think this one can go higher on some graphics cards). My point is that Vulkan limits you from spamming objects like there's no tomorrow, and is optimized around it. That optimization, for example, is why Elden Ring was choppy at launch, and why Wine could fix the problem on the driver side by caching command buffers.

Comment: @Blindy: "*texture object limits are also system-dependent*" There are no "texture object limits" in Vulkan. "*as low as 300ish on some devices*" What devices are those?

Comment: @Blindy: "*Descriptor objects are also limited, up to 4K base*" This is also not true. There is no upper bounds on `VkCreateDescriptorPoolInfo::maxSets`. There are limits on the number of each kind of descriptor that can be used by shaders at any one time. But those limits exist in OpenGL too. That's not a limitation on the number of "descriptor objects" (which is not a thing in Vulkan; you allocate sets); it's a limitation on the number of descriptors *used*.